# How can two GameObjects at different positions in the world space have the same position values under the transform attribute?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two gameobjects at different positions in the world space. But the position values under the transform attribute shows the same value.One object is a cube and the other one is a chess piece (a prefab).[Here is the screenshot of the window with the objects.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrjtu.jpg) I'm completely new to unity and it would so helpful if someone could help me sort this out.Thanks.[The screenshot the whole window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDtTg.jpg)

Comment: Maybe the position set to local rather than global.

Comment: make sure both object are independent not child/parent of one another

Comment: They are completely independent objects. Neither of them has a child/parent relationship.

Comment: If any answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the right one. _(Accepting an answer helps future visitors coming on this page)_

Answer (score 1):

If none of them isn't child of other gameObjects ,then maybe pivot of chess gameObject is not in center of your mesh ,check your 3D model of chess and set its pivot to center of gameObject.

Answer (score 0):

Your chess piece is certainly set as child of an object located around (X=3.5, Y=2.0, Z=4.5) coordinates. Unity displays the *localPosition* of Transform components.

Comment: But the chess piece isn't a child of any other object. I have added the image of the whole window.

Comment: @amith_ajith Looking at your 2nd provided screenshot, I'd say that the problem comes from your chess piece model. Try to switch the tool handle from _Center_ to _Pivot_ (in the top left of the screen). It's possible that your piece center is 0,0,0 while the model is not correctly placed.

Answer (score 0):

In your print screen you have scaled one of the objects 10 times. Could it be that the anchor of that object is at 0, 0, 0 but the rendered Chess piece is then rendered with offset.

Expand your mesh renderer and see if there are any offset variables